# How could I get rid of "PRF0002: Instrumentation failed with these options" error with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Profiler?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, profiler

I am now using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Performance Profiler to profile one program. It works very well when I use CPU sampling method. However, when I use Instrumentation method, I get the following error message:

```
PRF0002: Instrumentation failed with these options: /u "my program" /excludesmallfuns. Please check the output window for additional details.
```

I was wondering how I could get rid of this error. Thanks!

Comment: same here in VS2012 and VS2013 (after introducing `AsParallel()` to speed up some tasks)

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn on profiling for executable and .dll's you're about to profile (See this [Microsoft documentation on /PROFILE linker option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/profile-performance-tools-profiler?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019) )
2. From Performance profiler > Settings > Additional Instrumentation options - add multiple `/include:<function name>` or `/include:<class name>::<function name>`, where function name can be replaced with `*` asterisk. For some reason pressing `'Ok'` did not work for me - needed to press `'Apply'` first, only then settings would be taking into use. (Using Visual studio 2019, 16.4.3) Using `/verbose` can be used to troubleshoot instrumentation problems. Full list of options can be found here: [Microsoft documentation on VSInstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/vsinstr?view=vs-2017).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, and what fixed it for me was removing all the extra bindings I had added to my website in IIS (express). 
So, if your situation allows for this approach, then:

1. Open IIS Manager
2. In the connection pane, expand "Sites"
3. Right-click on your website (or Default Web Site)
4. Select "Edit Bindings"
5. Select all bindings other than the default one with port 80
6. Click "Remove" and close the popup.
7. I also restarted IIS.

Restart Visual Studio, and hopefully your profiler works this time!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. It turned out that you have to turn on the linker profile switch for the part you want to profile. Here is how you can do that:
[turn on profiling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ays5x7b0.aspx). However in my case I was had build my executable and the required dlls with profiling on and that was creating the issue. As soon as I turned profiling flag off for my executable I was able to profile it using this method:
[profiling specific dlls msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385752.aspx)